# Github equivalent of Gitlab's "merged result pipelines"

Tags: github, github-actions

Gitlab has the concept of a "merged result pipeline", in which a pipeline can run against the results of merging the contents of a merge request with its target branch.  Does github have an equivalent feature?

Comment: `on: pull_request`, GITHUB_REF will point at a branch in which your changes have been merged.